# How to swipe in Mobile using coordinates ? i am using appium ,java

Tags: java, appium, swipe

Below code, I used but didn't work

```
try{
     driverNew.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new
     UiSelector().scrollable(true)"+".scrollToEnd(4);");
     } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got working code

Using Appium I found coordinated to swipe

**TouchAction swipe = new TouchAction(driverNew).press(PointOption.point(540, 1824))
.waitAction(waitOptions(ofMillis(800))).moveTo(PointOption.point(540, 672)).release().perform();**